# Quickbooks Online Error PHP

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

When I attempt to connect to QBO via the Consolibyte package I downloaded I get an error.

> Error Code: internal_error
>
> Message: Error getting application from request token
>
> You can contact us for further assistance. Error
>   Id:ixnkryec2iu513ef45f3f5xv-12940655

I have set up the `config.php` file as directed in the instructions and even got to the point of authorizing the application with Quickbooks but now when I navigate to the page it indicates that I am not logged in and when I click the "Connect to QuickBooks" button on the `index.php` page I get the error above. I'm not familiar enough with the process to know where to start troubleshooting this problem and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Link: http://production.technology-architects.com/unleashed_new/quickbook/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/

example_app_ipp_v3/config.php code

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../QuickBooks.php';
$token = 'f5ddd229b1d19b4153b8218b08b97897050f';
$oauth_consumer_key = 'qyprdYvvyNLq1om6FSw0xLebctZEAz';
$oauth_consumer_secret = 'KCLYZRgZ4LnHUB35AzvylxnH6c8CDCyjhva8I9Gp';
$sandbox = true;     // When you're using development tokens
$quickbooks_oauth_url = 'http://production.technology-architects.com/unleashed_new/quickbook/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/oauth.php';
$quickbooks_success_url = 'http://production.technology-architects.com/unleashed_new/quickbook/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/success.php';
$quickbooks_menu_url = 'http://production.technology-architects.com/unleashed_new/quickbook/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/menu.php';
$dsn = 'mysqli://myusername:mypassword@localhost/databasename';
$encryption_key = 'bcde1234';
$the_username = 'DO_NOT_CHANGE_MEddd';
$the_tenant = 'sdfaswrqwerqwr';
if (!QuickBooks_Utilities::initialized($dsn)){
    QuickBooks_Utilities::initialize($dsn);
}
$IntuitAnywhere = new QuickBooks_IPP_IntuitAnywhere($dsn, $encryption_key, $oauth_consumer_key, $oauth_consumer_secret, $quickbooks_oauth_url, $quickbooks_success_url);
if ($IntuitAnywhere->check($the_username, $the_tenant) and $IntuitAnywhere->test($the_username, $the_tenant)){   
    $quickbooks_is_connected = true;
    $IPP = new QuickBooks_IPP($dsn);
    $creds = $IntuitAnywhere->load($the_username, $the_tenant);
    $IPP->authMode(
            QuickBooks_IPP::AUTHMODE_OAUTH, 
            $the_username, 
            $creds);
    if ($sandbox){
        $IPP->sandbox(true);
    }
    $realm = $creds['qb_realm'];
    $Context = $IPP->context();
    $CompanyInfoService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_CompanyInfo();
    $quickbooks_CompanyInfo = $CompanyInfoService->get($Context, $realm);
} else {
    $quickbooks_is_connected = false;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: i have updated the post and put config.php code there kindly check that. if any other code needs i will also put that there

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your app at Developer.Intuit.com, so we can confirm all of your tokens, URLs, etc. are correct.

Comment: kindly check the app by logging using the following credentials
Email: enginnerjavaid@gmail.com
Password: Swatswat556@

Comment: i have used this code https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php and instructions http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Intuit_Partner_Platform_Quick-Start

Comment: i have added the screenshots kindly take a look

Answer (score 0):

None of the tokens or OAuth credentials you have in your code match what you have in the screenshot.

Fix your tokens and OAuth values.

```
$token = 'f5ddd229b1d19b4153b8218b08b97897050f';
$oauth_consumer_key = 'qyprdYvvyNLq1om6FSw0xLebctZEAz';
$oauth_consumer_secret = 'KCLYZRgZ4LnHUB35AzvylxnH6c8CDCyjhva8I9Gp';
```

Comment: i have used another app and that have these credentials however i have checked it it,s not this problem

Comment: The credentials are specific to each app. Those credentials will only work with A SINGLE app. They are for the app itself. If you want help, post your code WITH THE CORRECT CREDENTIALS so that we can actually help you.